# Nested document query mongodb (dot notation not working)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a nested document in share --> content--> creator.
Currently i have a creatorId (_id of the creator object) and i am trying to find all shares with a content mapped to the creator.

But no matter how i try (for dot notation) it dosen't seem to work. Here's what i have tried (where creatorId is a string of the id of the nested document:

```
let shares = await Share.find({"content.creator": ObjectId(creatorId)})
    
let shares = await Share.find({"content.creator": creatorId)})

let shares = await Share.find({"content.creator._id": creatorId})
```

What am i doing wrong? Thanks!

```
  Share: { _id: 5f1690a8d15ff6558cb48cc1,
      __v: 0,
      content:
       { _id: 5f1690a7d15ff6558cb48cc0,        
         creator:
          { _id: 5f166ce0c6b1744fee6b28e7,},
            __v: 0, 
          }
    }
```

Comment: Please tell which value you want to match ? creator is object type

Comment: Oh i'm matching by the _id

Comment: Have you tried `"content.creator._id"` then?

Comment: yup i tried that, and didn't work either. Just added to the 'what i have tried' list

Comment: Please check here https://mongoplayground.net/p/Y5Vzu8MiNV2

Answer (score 0):

```
Please find use objectId type

db.collection.find({
       "content.creator._id": ObjectId("5f166ce0c6b1744fee6b28e7")
})
```

Comment: sorry , still empty result

Comment: per your mongoplayground above 
await Share.find({
   "content.creator._id": "5f166ce0c6b1744fee6b28e7"
  })

Comment: Please sir use ObjectId type for match
ObjectId("5f166ce0c6b1744fee6b28e7")

Comment: still blank using this:   let shares = await Share.find({
   "content.creator._id": ObjectId("5f166ce0c6b1744fee6b28e7")
  })

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218263/discussion-between-mahesh-bhatnagar-and-daniel-shen).